# Why is Suara "All about music and cats"?

Tags: house, techno

Since founding Spanish record label Suara in 2008, Coyu has been using iconic photos of cats illustrated below. What is the the true story behind these cute little kitties, featuring on every EP and album cover to date?

[image: Tube & Berger - Imprint of PLeasure EP]
[image: Jay Lumen - Raw Basses EP]
[image: Coyu - Party Groovers Vol. 3]
[image: Leonardo Gonnelli - Get Started]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

*So Suara is all about music and cats. Can you tell us a bit about these two values? How long have you been a cat lover?*

> Well, my girlfriend is a feline vet, she works with animals, especially with cats. When I was a kid, I never was a cat lover, but a dog lover. After my girlfriend, I have realized that cats are so beautiful, I love them so much. Now, at home, we have a foundation for street cats as well. We love cats and that’s why they are in my posts all the time, and that’s why we try to pay them back something, that’s why we have the foundation.
>
> At the beginning of my life, I was a dog lover, and actually I still
>   love dogs. I am a cat lover, but still a dog lover.

*I have noticed that you take this philosophy a bit further with the [Suara Foundation](https://www.facebook.com/suarafoundation). Can you tell me a bit about what the foundation is all about?*

> We are just trying to give back something. The scene now, Suara is a lover of the cats, so we want to support them as much as we can. Paying vet costs, and now in Ibiza we are going to to give some money to cat hospitals and shelters, and some benefits of the party in Ibiza go straight to the cat shelters and that operation. You know, we love cats, so we try to help them.

References:

- [We chat with the big cat Coyu of Suara [Interview] - Magnetic Magazine](http://www.magneticmag.com/2014/08/interview-big-cat-coyu-concerned-quality/)